# SELECT Rows Between two Number column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

Hi i am having Ranking table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ranking](
[Code] [varchar](5) NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[RankFrom] [varchar](5) NULL,
[RankTo] [varchar](5) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Adding following Values

```
INSERT INTO [Ranking]([Code],[Name],[RankFrom],[RankTo])VALUES('01','Hisanth','105','110')
```

My result as follows when my query is

select * from Ranking

| Code | Name | RankFrom | RankTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Hisanth | 105 | 110 |

But I need to get result like as follows

| Code | Name | RankTo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Hisanth | 105 |
| 01 | Hisanth | 106 |
| 01 | Hisanth | 107 |
| 01 | Hisanth | 108 |
| 01 | Hisanth | 109 |
| 01 | Hisanth | 110 |

How to write query for this

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select code, name, rankfrom, rankto from ranking
    union all
    select code, name, rankfrom, rankto - 1 from cte where rankto > rankfrom
)
select code, name, rankto from cte
```

If your ranges may be greater than 100, then you need to add `option(maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.

---

If you really are storing these numbers as strings (which obviously is not a good idea), then you would need to convert them first:

```
with cte as (
    select code, name, convert(int, rankfrom) as rankfrom, convert(int, rankto) as rankto from ranking
    union all
    select code, name, rankfrom, rankto - 1 from cte where rankto > rankfrom
)
select code, name, rankto from cte
```

Comment: it shows error like as --- Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "rankto" of recursive query "cte".

Comment: @Hisanth: are you really storing these numbers as strings? That's not a good idea. In any case, you would need to convert them to numbers. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The use of recusion is the worst thing to do in terms of performances. You never should write a CTE recursive query like the one that have been given in the first answer, but create a hard table of number into your database, like this one :

```
CREATE TABLE N (i INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO N VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);
INSERT INTO N
SELECT N1.i + 10*N2.i + 100*N3.i + 1000*N4.i
FROM   N AS N1
       CROSS JOIN N AS N2
       CROSS JOIN N AS N3
       CROSS JOIN N AS N4
WHERE  N1.i + 10*N2.i + 100*N3.i + 1000*N4.i >= 10;
```

Then the answer is trivial :

```
SELECT R.* 
FROM   Ranking AS R
       JOIN N ON i BETWEEN R.RANKFROM AND R.RANKTO;
```

To execute it faster, create an index like this one :

```
CREATE INDEX X_RNK_FROM_TO ON Ranking (RANKFROM, RANKTO);
```

To have much more speed, store the N table in a readonly filegroup.

IN CONCLUSION : every database should have a number table and a calendar one. They are called tally table and are a great use for this typical cases.